# Is there a technology that can cache an ordered list and retrieve sorted results from arbitrary points in the ordering?

Tags: caching

Imagine a timeline like a Twitter stream, where you want to quickly return a result for all items after date n. Is there a caching technology like Memcache that can cache this data in a way that can be queried in order, dropping older items to make room for new data?

I would imagine the interface would work like the following:

Adding items would always add to the head of the list.

```
Cache.add(key, timestamp, data)
```

Items could be queried given a timestamp.

```
Cache.getAfter(key, timestamp)
```

The .get() function would be guaranteed to not return items older than the given timestamp, and would return items starting from the head of the list ordered oldest to newest.

When the cache needs to evict items, items with the oldest timestamps are removed first.

Comment: Is there some reason why an SQL database cannot be used?  It would certainly provide good support for that kind of query.

Comment: A SQL database will be providing the raw data, but the goal is to have an in-memory caching layer between the SQL database and the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a Redis list is the best solution.

With the [LPUSH](http://redis.io/commands/lpush) and [LTRIM](http://redis.io/commands/ltrim) commands, you can easily make a list that does not grow larger than N items.

```
LPUSH mylist someelement
LTRIM mylist 0 99
```